# Login a user with JWT (Json web token) and Devise in Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, devise, jwt

I am having a rails application in which one page is purly Angular operated (Like a single page application,including sign in/logout etc).

But at the same time there are some pages which we can not include on single page and we want to keep them separatly as they were working before in traditional way of rails.

So we have used JWT for sign in on Angular page ,but for traditional page we still have to use some authentication (Before we were using Devise)
since as user will move from single page application to Rails traditional page via an URL then how will I maintain the login session for that part of page which in Rails and required login (For availablity of current user)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your browser requirements, you could store the JWT in Local Storage, or in a cookie. It would still be secure, and you could then use the same JWT to authenticate the user no matter what page they are on.